# EF System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem in generating the EF model from Database SqlCe, in a c# project.
This is a new error because I've updated this many times in years.
I try many things to resolve it, also researching on the web, but nothing help me to resolve. I've changed also the NET Framework to 4.6.2.

The C# project uses NETFramework 4.5 and EF 6.2, EF.SqlCe 6.2.

This is the error message:

```
Generating the model took 00:00:30.5059377.
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderManifest.SupportsParameterOptimizationInSchemaQueries()'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.CreateFilteredCommand(String sql, String orderByClause, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, List`1 filters, String[] filterAliases)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadDataTable[T](String sql, Func`2 orderByFunc, DataTable table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, IEnumerable`1 filters, String[] filterAliases)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadTableDetails(IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:01.5131055.
Generating the model took 00:00:04.8109160.
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: [This has been reported by multiple people.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/539) The direct cause there appears to be a wrong version of `EntityFramework.dll` getting loaded, but the indirect cause, the reason why a wrong version gets loaded, may be different for each individual. Are you able to check which version of EF got loaded?

Answer (score 6):

Running (as administrator) this command worked for me:

```
gacutil /u EntityFramework
```

A Visual Studio restart is needed then. The older version of assembly probably installed to GAC.

Comment: This helped me in VS 2019.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue using VS 2017. Below are the steps I have taken to get rid of this issue.

1. Go to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntityFramework"
   folder location
2. Cut the "EntityFramework.dll" from the above folder
   and kept somewhere
3. Go to the EF project and update the model without any error

Hope this will helps. Thanks.

Comment: I think it worked, need to restart VS. (and I update Entity Framework nuget, dont know if that change anything of the success)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled VS 2017 and now works!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 packages referencing different versions of the same dll. For example the EntityFramework packages for mysql and sqlite referring to different versions of the EntityFramework core library

When viewed like that, the obvious fixes are to either

- Remove one of the conflicting packages  OR
- Ensure that you select a version for both packages which references either the same or a compatible version of the conflicting dll. The Nuget package manager is useful in this regard.

Bear in mind that, once in a while, your IDE might need a restart to capture any changes.